# apache httpcomponents.httpClient strangest error ever

Tags: java, android, apache, httpclient

we are developing an android app and my current part is to implement uploading files.
I'm using httpcore-4.2.2, httpclient-4.2.2 and httpmime-4.2.2.

My problem now is that the file will only be send with the httpclient if the URI has a really specific description... if I use another URI the post-body on the server-side is empty... and I am really not capable of understanding this issue.
My code looks as follows:

```
public static String getUploadLink()  {

    String server = Mobile4dApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.default_server_address);
    String parameter = "/Files/upload";


    String finalQuery = String.format("%s%s", server, parameter);
    Log.d("UploadService", finalQuery );
    return finalQuery;
}

private String uploadFile(String uploadURL, File uploadFile, String title, long id) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(  );
        multipartEntity.addPart( "file", new FileBody( uploadFile ) );
        HttpResult httpResult;
        try {
            httpResult = HttpCommunicator.sendPOST( uploadURL, multipartEntity );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // TODO remove sysout line when it is not needed anymore
        System.out.println("result: " + httpResult.getResultMessage());
        return httpResult.getResultMessage();
    }

public static HttpResult sendPOST(String targetURL, HttpEntity entity) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
    HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, connectionTimeoutMillis);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(targetURL);
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
    String result = "";
    if (response != null && response.getEntity() != null) {
        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), UTF_8_ENCODING);
    }

    return new HttpResult(result, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
```

if I use the URI serveraddress/Files/upload everything looks fine on the server side. But if I change the part with "Files/upload" even in the slightest the whole post-body turns out to be empty  when it reaches our server...
I am completely out of ideas... I really hope that someone can help...

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: the file itself should be irrelevant. It is taken with the camera of my android device. the thing is that it only works if the URI is serveraddress/Files/upload. in any other case it does not work...

Comment: oh and before I forget, this Files/upload was the first I ever tried. it worked in the beginning and later it did not anymore. It took me 3 days to locate that. I thought the whole time that the problem is on the server side but it wasn't

Comment: I need to correct myself. I just wrote a pure java-Client for the server that executes the same request as my android client. the problem is still there but I used a proxy that showed the request content to me. The request is sent correctly to the server. but the server does not find the parameters...